# Does anybody know what a low-degree Markov field is?

Tags: error-correction, quantum-operation, pauli-gates, noise, error-mitigation

In the paper *[Fast Estimation of Sparse Quantum Noise](https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/abstract/10.1103/PRXQuantum.2.010322)* I saw the following description:

> quantum devices approaching the fault-tolerant regime will have very
> few significant errors (and therefore are approximately sparse) and
> will have errors that are only weakly correlated (and therefore are
> approximated by a low-degree Markov field)

What is a low-degree Markov field?

Comment: Could you include a reference.

Comment: https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/abstract/10.1103/PRXQuantum.2.010322